# Bulk insert fmt text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulkinsert, bcp

I've a BULK INSERT task that takes data from a csv and imports into a table.  Only problem is that one of the columns can contain a comma, so the import doesn't work as expected.

I've tried to fix this by creating a format (fmt) file, the contents of which I've detailed below:-

```
9.0
6
1       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       1     "Identifier"                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       2     "Name"                                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       3     "Date of Birth"                                            Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       4     "Admission"                                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       5     "Code"                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\r\n"   6     "Length"                                                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

The column causing me pain is column 2 "Name".

I've tried a couple of things to identify the column as being text qualified and containing a comma but I'm not getting the result I want.

If I change to the following:-

`"\","` - I get something like this -- "Richardson, Mat

This isn't correct, so I tried this instead, as suggested on some other forums / sites:-

```
"\",\""
```

This doesn't work at all and actually gives me the error

```
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
```

I've tried a few other combinations and just can't get this right.  Any help or guidance would  be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question regarding format files but a possible get you working solution.

Format files are incomprehensible arcana from the 1980s to me, bulk insert is uber fussy and unforgiving. Therefore I tend to clean data with a few lines of powershell instead. Here's an example I used recently to convert a CSV to Pipe separated, to remove some random quoting on the output and to allow for commas in the records:

```
Import-Csv -Path  $dirtyCsv | 
ConvertTo-CSV  -NoType -Delimiter '|' | 
%{ $_.Replace('"','') } | 
Out-File $cleanCsv
```

You get the idea...

This then simply imported:

```
BULK INSERT SomeTable FROM 'clean.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you are telling the bulk insert that your field terminator for the column before name is a simple comma and that the field terminator for the `Name` column itself is double quote, then comma. You need to change the field terminator for the column before `Name` to be comma then double quote if you want to take care of the remaining double quote.

I believe your field terminator for the column before name should be: `",\""`, where:

- `,`=comma
- `/"` = double quotes

Enclosed in another set of double quotes; it is the value to be used as the field terminator.

Flip the comma and the double quotes for the field terminator of your `Name` column.

So it should look like this:

```
9.0
6
1       SQLCHAR       0       50      ",\""       1     "Identifier"                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\","       2     "Name"                                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       3     "Date of Birth"                                            Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       4     "Admission"                                                Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       50      ","       5     "Code"                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\r\n"   6     "Length"
```